# multiple ajax requests giving 504 gateway timeouts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building a very large pdf book using PHP, I am using ajax to trigger the script. My issue is that because it so big it was timing out, so I decided to break it and recursively call the script several times. I tested this a few weeks back and it was fine. However now I am getting random "504 gateway timeout" issues with some of the ajax calls.

Im not sure where to even begin debugging this as I believed the entire purpose of doing several ajax calls was to prevent this issue. Unfortunately I dont have access to the server as its on a shared hosting package.

```
<?php $i =1; for($i;$i<=$number_of_pages;$i++) { ?>
<?php if ($i == $number_of_pages) { $last = 1; } else { $last = 0; } ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.waiting-gif').show(); 
    var number_of_pages = '<?php echo $number_of_pages; ?>';
    var build_progress_width = 480/number_of_pages;

    var last = '<?php echo $last; ?>';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=pdfengine/pdfengine/trigger_pdf_gen',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {     
            pdf_id : '<?php echo $this->request->get['pdf_id']; ?>',
            page_number: '<?php echo $i; ?>',
        },
        beforeSend: function() {



        },
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(json) {
            $('.build-progress-green').css('width', build_progress_width);
            $('.pdf-build-progress').append('<div class="build-progress-green"></div>');




            if (last == '1') {

                $.ajax({
                        url: 'index.php?route=pdfengine/pdfengine/merge_pdfs',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {     
                            pdf_id : '<?php echo $this->request->get['pdf_id']; ?>',

                        },
                        beforeSend: function() {},
                        complete: function() {},
                        success: function(json) {

                            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
                            // Set the link to the json response
                            link.href = json['download_link'];
                            $('#downloadlink').attr('download','reads-pdf-id-' + json['pdf_id'] + '.pdf');
                            // Unhide the link
                            link.style.display = 'block';
                            $('#downloadlink').trigger('click');
                            $('.waiting-gif').hide();



                        }
                    });
            }
        }


        });
    });



</script>
<?php } ?>
```

The main function being called via ajax...

```
 public function trigger_pdf_gen() {

    if(isset($this->request->post['pdf_id'])) {

        $this->load->model('pdfengine/pdfengine');       

        $pdf_info = $this->model_pdfengine_pdfengine->getPdfInfo($this->request->post['pdf_id']);

        $page_number = $this->request->post['page_number'];

        $this->session->data['childs_name'] = $pdf_info[0]['childs_name'];
        $this->session->data['pdf_id'] = $pdf_info[0]['pdf_id'];    
        $this->session->data['gift_message'] = $pdf_info[0]['gift_message'];                
        $double_pages = explode(',',$this->model_pdfengine_pdfengine->getDoublePages($pdf_info[0]['book_path']));
        $is_double_page = 0;
        foreach ($double_pages as $double_page) {


            if ($double_page == $page_number) { $is_double_page = 1;  } 

        }

        $this->generate_final_pdf($pdf_info[0]['pdf_id'],$pdf_info[0]['book_path'],$pdf_info[0]['childs_gender'], $page_number,$is_double_page );


        $json = array();
        $json[] = "<a href='".DIR_FINAL_PDFS_PUBLIC.$pdf_info[0]['pdf_id']."/final-build-".$pdf_info[0]['pdf_id'].".pdf'>The file :)</a>";
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));

    }        


 }
```

Is it possible this could be a temporary server related issue?

Comment: Where is the loop closed?

Comment: at the very end underneath `</script>`

Comment: I copied the code into my IDE and reformatted it to make it easier to find and the closing brace after script is for the else block, not the loop.

Comment: I just want to make sure that it has the loop fully closed and that there isn't any tailing code that didn't get copied to the example above.

Comment: cheers, im amended the code and wrapped brackets around the else, however Id be fairly confident that has nothing to do with the issue. Ive been using that code for a while, its only when I try to run quite a few of them together did this problem arise

Comment: can yoyu show the file which ajax is calling?

Comment: there's quite a few functions within the main function called, I was going to post it all , but it would lots and lots of code, and I figured because its been working ok with 1 I didnt see how the code could be relevent , however Ill edit the question now and add the main function

Comment: have a look here http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/504error.htm

Comment: interesting thanks, it hadnt occured to me that it may be an issue from the office end, and nothing to do with the site

Comment: So why are you building this PDF on the fly? Does it get customized per user? Otherwise you should just pre-compile it and have the user download it. If you can just serve them the pages one at a time then you should call single pages and display then load the next/previous page on click of the next/previous button on the page. I can give you a great example as to how to do that.

Comment: If it does get customized then you could send it to a queue and use a process server, such as Iron.io's Iron Worker, to build the individual PDFs and then have a download link sent to them or displayed on the page. What this does is offloads the computing of the file generation to another server. It allows greater concurrency and much faster performance.

Comment: I could also send examples of that as well.

Comment: Hi, the pdf must be built on the fly alright, its totally customized, I changed the code and got rid of the for loop and did the loop with javascript instead, will post an answer in a few mins

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, I wouldnt call it a solution exactly but it does the job.

I scrapped the for loop and forced each trigger of ajax request on a time delay using javascript.

```
var counter = 1;
trigger_pdf();
var i = setInterval( trigger_pdf, 61000); 

function trigger_pdf() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=pdfengine/pdfengine/trigger_pdf_gen',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {     
        pdf_id : '<?php echo $this->request->get['pdf_id']; ?>',
        page_number: counter,
    },
    beforeSend: function() {



    },
    complete: function() {},
    error: function() {
        alert('Build failed and timed out, please contact ####');
    },
    success: function(json) {
        $('.build-progress-green').css('width', build_progress_width);
        $('.pdf-build-progress').append('<div class="build-progress-green"></div>');


    }


});

if(counter == number_of_pages) { 
    clearInterval(i);
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=pdfengine/pdfengine/merge_pdfs',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {     
                        pdf_id : '<?php echo $this->request->get['pdf_id']; ?>',

                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {},
                    complete: function() {},
                    success: function(json) {

                        var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
                        // Set the link to the json response
                        link.href = json['download_link'];
                        $('#downloadlink').attr('download','reads-pdf-id-' + json['pdf_id'] + '.pdf');
                        // Unhide the link
                        link.style.display = 'block';
                        $('#downloadlink').trigger('click');
                        $('.waiting-gif').hide();



                    }
                });     
}
counter++;


}
```